# How to change json key with react "onchange"?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have some problem. I have got a form with to input. 1 input - key, 2 input - value. I need to change the values in the states when changing the value in the input fields, but I don't know how to do it. **Json must be in this format only.**

```
myjson = {
'hello': 'world',
'foo':'bar',
'bar':'foo',
'How':'are u'
 }
```

I'm set to inputs onChange event and this function

```
    this.setState({
       variables: {
         ...this.state.variables, [this.props.fix]: {
           ...this.state.variables[this.props.fix],[this.props.parentkey]: e.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

But the problem remains, because `[this.props.parentkey]` will always be one, since the values of key are kept in the `e.target.value`. If I change it to `[e.target.value]:e.target.value` a bunch of new elements will be generated, and not one instead of the old one

my inputs

```
<ValidationForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<FormGroup>
      <TextInput name="parentkey"
                 onChange={this.Change}
                 value={this.state.parentkey}
      />
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup>
      <TextInput name="customvalue"
                 onChange={this.Change}
                 value={this.state.translate}
      />
</FormGroup>
<button>Save</button>
</ValidationForm>
```

**How to be in this situation?**

Comment: I actually cannot understand what you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state={

 parentkey: '',
 transalte: '',

}

change = (e) => {
  this.setState({
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
 })

 }
```

> Now the Html Part

```
       <ValidationForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <FormGroup>
  <TextInput name="parentkey"
             onChange={this.Change}
             value={this.state.parentkey}
       />
    </FormGroup>
     <FormGroup>
      <TextInput name="translate"
             onChange={this.Change}
             value={this.state.translate}
  />
  </FormGroup>
  <button>Save</button>
 </ValidationForm>
```